# Brushfire and GVD implementation in c++

Tags: c++, diagram, voronoi, motion-planning

I have an assignment where I need to use the Brushfire Algorithm to **implement a Generalized Voronoi Diagram(GVD)** and use it for path planning.

I have already implemented the Brushfire Algorithm, but don't know how to implement the GVD.

I'm using c++

Can anyone help me pleeeease!??? :D

Comment: What is your question? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know how to get started.
Can you maybe come up with a pseudo code for how to implement a GVD using brushfire algorithm??

Comment: I assume that you mean Voronoi diagram of points and straight-line segments when you talk about "Generalized Voronoi diagram". Then you may want to look at [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_diagram.htm) for a free implementation. Alternatively you may look at [CGAL](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dock/manuals/cgal_manual/Segment_Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html) as well. If you want to implement this on your own then count in 6-12 months at least.